# VBA: for loop skip if cell matches another column

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement

How can I loop trough a column and skip the rows where the cell value matches a list in another sheet?

```
For Counter = 2 To 5
    rst.AddNew
        rst.Fields("Title") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 1).Value
        rst.Fields("Names") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value
    
    Next Counter
```

As you can see I have a simple for loop which will loop trough row 2 to 5, but I wanted to check if the value in the cell matches what is in another tab, and if so I wanted to skip that row.

Comment: you can test whether `Application.Match()` is an error or not, if error it does not exist.  the arguments are `(whatToLookUp,LookupRange,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say column to check is Column E

```
Dim ColumnToCheck as Range
 Set ColumnToCheck=range("Sheets2!E:E")

    For Counter = 2 To 5
       
       ValueToCheck= Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 1).Value

       If Not IsError(Application.Match(ValueToCheck, ColumnToCheck,0)) Then
            rst.AddNew
            rst.Fields("Title") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 1).Value
            rst.Fields("Names") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value
      End If   

     Next Counter
```

Comment: Wow! that is what i was looking for! I did something similar, but nothing happens... :(

Comment: So if you liked it, mark it as accepted solution

Comment: Yup, just did!, sorry im quite new to the site :)

Comment: @King It's not accepted yet.